# Is there any Python-like programming language with voluntary static typing?

Tags: python, programming-languages, duck-typing, static-typing

Is there any programming language out there which is just like Python, but allows you to **voluntarily** specify the type of any variable/parameter/return-value explicitly, so that whenever you indeed do that – the IDE could enforces some type constrains?

Comment: Python 3.5 has `type hints`, and see [Python 3.5 type hinting in PyCharm 5](http://blog.jetbrains.com/pycharm/2015/11/python-3-5-type-hinting-in-pycharm-5/)

Comment: What is the downvote for? It's not that bad question.

Comment: @furas Cool thanks!!

Answer (score 2):

[boo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boo_(programming_language)) and [cython](http://cython.org/) - The first is somewhat a "one man project" language to the `.net` platform, the second is a complete, real Python superset which compiles to C and them to object code, and is in ide use to create Python libraries requiring native code, or wrappers to call binary libraries.

Comment: Thanks!
I understand those alternatives are not interactive interpreters such as Python (correct me if I'm wrong).

Comment: I don't know about boo - it should be possible to have an interactive Cython interpreter, by modifying a Python REPL loop - and it looks like tehre is an iPython extension that allows for interactive use of Cython already: https://acsgsoc15.wordpress.com/2015/04/07/using-cython-in-ipython/